# Are there any crypto hash implementation beyond 512 bits of output?

Tags: hash, sha-3, sha-512

My question is this: Are there any crypto hash implementations beyond 512 bits of output?

Could you give me the link?

Thank you so much for your time.

Greetings.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3 with the variable parameter `d`

Comment: This is for my homework, if you could just give me some link of the implementation?

Comment: For example I got this of 768 bits output: cded98730118b7a4a15597430c9d75863d9532329540cab109ea26ab72a96d1b30c264e213beef31700795f4bb881bf0fd10ce945b15a8557dac5d970b49d75b6e8904776c7d3b5b975228ead94f06dbeb97574581bf53ac4b82ae93ec4f77c7

Comment: And I mean "Output size in bits" and not "Block size in bits", I'm looking for 1024 and 2048 bits of output for my homework, does any one have the link?
Thank you so much for your time!!!

Comment: I just google sha3 2048 bits of output implementation for any programming language and no results. maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: XOF hash functions (extendible output functions) are hash functions that support generating arbitrarily large outputs.

Comment: Yes for sure, look just gimme some 1024 o 2048 sample, this is just for my homework, sincerely regards!!!

Comment: Uh, 1. that's not in your question and 2. I think you misunderstand the term "homework", it is something that *you* perform inside *your* home, not *we* in *our home*.

Comment: My question, once again, is this: Could you provide me a link for a crypto hash implementation beyond 512 bits, or could you be so generous to provide me with some sample output hash? This is for some personal homework in my own house.Thank\

Comment: https://github.com/BLAKE3-team/BLAKE3 supports XOF mode (arbitrary length output). Note: it's not SHA3. Since you want SHA3, pick literally any implementation of it and use the XOF modes.

Comment: Her's a shake link for you. Happy programming. https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/shake128.html

Comment: I want to note that even if SHAKE supports the output length of more than 512, its cryptographic strength [cannot exceed 128/256 bits](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43718/if-the-output-size-of-shake128-256-is-variable-why-is-the-security-fixed-at-128). So I wouldn't call such output "hash". The notion of "cryptographically secure hash" of length N is different from the notion of "the output of an XOF" of length N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any hash function with a stream cipher or block cipher in streaming mode like CTR/OFB to produce arbitrary length output beyond 512 bits.

Another method is using extendable-output functions (XOFs). XOF is a hash function that its output can be extended to any length. [Keccak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) (SHA-3), [Skein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skein_%28hash_function%29) and [BLAKE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAKE_(hash_function)) have extendable output mode.

[There](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/shake128.html) [are](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/shake256.html) [many](https://github.com/topics/shake128) [implementations](https://github.com/topics/shake256) of [SHAKE128](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/shake_128.html)/[SHAKE256](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/shake_256.html) (SHA-3's XOF).

Comment: Since you are a new contributor to our site, you might note that we don't answer homework questions, we only provide a hint for them in the comments if they show some efforts. You can search and find our community agreement on the meta site. Also, this question is already a library/software recommendation and out of the scope of Cryptography.SE, too. Warm welcomes...

Comment: @kelalaka OK, Thanks.